# Team Foundation/SQL/Silverlight creation of new team project failure Timeout

Tags: sql, visual-studio, silverlight, reporting-services, tfs

This is a rather convoluted problem, because we are setting up TFS with SQL Reporting running with SilverLight Integration. We followed the horrific path of set-up instructions that range across 3 different servers, and when we finished, we started getting the following error.

This error results from attempting to create a new team project within the project group.

Following its progress in the reports page, we can see it create the folders cleanly, but when it attempts to create the actual reports on the system, it times out. I've checked every other site I could find to try and figure out what went wrong, and nothing suggested has worked. Any help here would be greatly appreciated

Error/Stack Trace attached below:

```
  2011-01-19T15:54:21 | Module: Engine | Thread: 6 | Running Task "" from Group ""
    2011-01-19T15:54:24 | Module: Rosetta | Thread: 19 | Creating folder: /TfsReports/Boeing/admin/Bugs
    2011-01-19T15:54:25 | Module: Rosetta | Thread: 19 | Creating folder: /TfsReports/Boeing/admin/Builds
    2011-01-19T15:54:26 | Module: Rosetta | Thread: 19 | Creating folder: /TfsReports/Boeing/admin/Project Management
    2011-01-19T15:54:27 | Module: Rosetta | Thread: 19 | Creating folder: /TfsReports/Boeing/admin/Tests
    2011-01-19T15:54:29 | Module: Rosetta | Thread: 19 | Creating folder: /TfsReports/Boeing/admin/Dashboards
    2011-01-19T15:54:30 | Module: Rosetta | Thread: 19 | Creating report: /TfsReports/Boeing/admin/Bugs/Bug Status
    ---begin Exception entry---
    Time: 2011-01-19T15:59:30
    Module: Engine
    Event Description: TF30162: Task "Populate Reports" from Group "Reporting" failed
    Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
    Exception Message: TF30225: Error uploading report 'Bug Status': The operation has timed out
    Stack Trace:
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.RosettaReportUploader.Execute(ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.ProjectCreationEngine.TaskExecutor.PerformTask(IProjectComponentCreator componentCreator, ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.ProjectCreationEngine.RunTask(Object taskObj)
    --   Inner Exception   --
    Exception Message: TF30225: Error uploading report 'Bug Status': The operation has timed out (type ReportingUploaderException)

    Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Reporting.ReportingUploader.UploadReport(XmlNode report)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Reporting.ReportingUploader.HandleCreateReports(XmlNode node)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Reporting.ReportingUploader.Run()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.RosettaReportUploader.Execute(ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)

    Inner Exception Details:

    Exception Message: The operation has timed out (type WebException)
    Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationSoapProxy.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Reporting.ReportingService.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Reporting.ReportingUploader.UploadReport(XmlNode report)

    --- end Exception entry ---

    2011-01-19T15:59:31 | Module: Engine | Thread: 19 | TF30202: Task "" from Group "" will not be run because a prior task failed.
    2011-01-19T15:59:31 | Module: Engine | Thread: 19 | TF30202: Task "SharePointPortal" from Group "Portal" will not be run because a prior task failed.
    2011-01-19T15:59:31 | Module: Engine | Thread: 19 | TF30202: Task "" from Group "" will not be run because a prior task failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denis Habib posted [this solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/251f0534-82af-45a2-bb6e-f2ae4ef76581) to a similar problem. Perhaps you have the same problem

> The problem is with uploading a report
>   to the report server.  I think you
>   have the correct permissions since you
>   were able to create the site.  The
>   problem may have to do with the
>   security settings on the datasources
>   (TfsOlapReportDS and TfsReportDS) as
>   these are the datasources for the
>   reports.
>
> Please verify the following settings: 
>   Navigate to the reporting site
>   (/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx">http:///Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx),
>   click on the TfsOlapReportsDS and the
>   TfsReportDS and verify the connection
>   settings for each, specifically the
>   'Connect using:' section.  This is
>   generally set to 'Credentials stored
>   securely in the report server' and a
>   valid username/password is specified. 
>   Also, the 'Use as Windows credentials
>   when connection to the data source' is
>   checked.

Comment: I've seen similar issues with permissions wind up showing up as a timeout error as well.  This is probably a good place to start.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the Reporting Services log file for the TFS Reporting Services instance.  In my case, it was a security issue and the exact stored procedure it was trying to run (but couldn't) was detailed in the log.

Comment: In our case, the backing Reporting Services database was migrated to a new SQL Server instance, however the RsExecRole security was not setup on the new SQL Server instance as documented in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281308.aspx).  We run our reporting services instance as a domain account and that account needed to be added to the new RSExecRole on SQL Server instance as well as the appropriate grants to the objects in the master database.